# Why was the operation resumed from checkpoint in the first place?

Tags: gem5, checkpoint

When I was looking at the source code of a top meeting implemented on gem5, they all first used `--take-checkpoint=$INST_TAKE_CHECKPOINT` to generate a check-point of 100,000 instructions. When it is actually running, start running from the check-point. But I always thought that check-point is to recover when the program crashes? Or divide a large benchmark into several runs? But why do you checkpoint at the very beginning? What is the meaning of this?

Answer (score 0):

The main application of checkpoints in my experience is to fast forward simulations past boot (done with a fast CPU) and then start running the content of in a detailed CPU, related: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/69511/what-does-fast-forwarding-mean-in-the-context-of-cpu-simulation/120980#120980

I think the motivation of `--take-checkpoint` to take multiple checkpoints is as you said to divide a large benchmark into multiple runs. It might make sense to first to a fast Atomic run until the end, generate several checkpoints, and then do more detailed and slower runs starting from the checkpoints across several different machines to parallelize the work, and then combine results somehow.